# How to add a CSS property to selected nodes on sigma.js (canvas renderer)

Tags: javascript, canvas, sigma.js

I have created a functions that, when I click on a node, makes all non-neighboring nodes transparent*. Now I would like to make the same nodes unresponsive to mouse events, while keeping visible nodes responsive.
One option would be to assign the css attribute `pointer-events:none` to transparent nodes. Can I do this with sigma?

*To do so I assign an rgba color with opacity 0. Hence I must use the canvas renderer because WebGL does not support transparency.

My code:

```
function highlight () {

var s = sigma.instances()[0];
var nodes = s.graph.nodes();
var edges = s.graph.edges();
var maxCollab = d3.max(edges, function(d) { return d.collaborations; });

// We first need to save the original colors of our
// nodes and edges, like this:
nodes.forEach(function(n) {
    n.originalColor = n.color;
  });
edges.forEach(function(e) {
    e.originalColor = e.color;
  });

// When a node is clicked, we check for each node
// if it is a neighbor of the clicked one. If not,
// we set its color as grey, and else, it takes its
// original color.
// We do the same for the edges, and we only keep
// edges that have both extremities colored.
s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
    var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
        toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
    toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;

    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      if (toKeep[n.id])
        n.color = n.originalColor;
      else
        n.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    });

    edges.forEach(function(e) {
      if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target]) {
        e.color = e.originalColor;
    }
      else
        e.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    });

    // Since the data has been modified, we need to
    // call the refresh method to make the colors
    // update effective.
    s.refresh();
});

// When the stage is clicked, we just color each
// node and edge with its original color.
s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      n.color = n.originalColor;
    });

    edges.forEach(function(e) {
      e.color = e.originalColor;
    });
    s.refresh();
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to hide the nodes? If so, you could set the hidden property of the nodes  to true. This way they wouldn't be visible anymore and sigma wouldn't fire any events for them.

Comment: Yes setting `node.hidden = true` worked for my case indeed! However, I still think ti'd be useful to be able to change css attributes through events.

Comment: The problem here is, that you cannot assign css classes to an element of sigma.js that is rendered by a canvas or a webgl renderer, because they are simply not part of the DOM. 

I think you would have to use a svg renderer for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a flag onto the node(s) meant to be unresponsive to the `clickNode` event.

```js
// excerpt from `clickNode` handler
nodes.forEach(function(n) {
  if (toKeep[n.id]) {
    n.color = n.originalColor;
    n.clickable = false; // <-- add this
  } else {
    n.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  }
});
```

Then only let the contents of the `clickNode` handler apply to those nodes.

```js
// `clickNode` handler
s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
    if (e.data.node.clickable) {
        // business as usual
    }
});
```

Don't forget to set the flag to `true` in your `clickStage` handler.